# ¿Debería ignorar en mi repositorio PHP el directorio vendor?

Tags: php, composer

Tengo un proyecto PHP en el que uso compose como gestor de dependencias, si quiero subir mi proyecto a un repositorio ¿Debería ignorar la carpeta vendor? digo esto por que entiendo que lo lógico seria que luego cuando se vaya a usar en un servidor o en local mediante el comando "composer install" se instalarían las dependencias automáticamente en esa carpeta, no se si esto que pienso es correcto o una tontearía.

Gracias.

Comment: Si, por la razon que dices

Comment: Es correcto. Igualmente te va a pasar con carpetas de log, temporales, directorios de upload, archivos de configuración específicos de tu equipo (.env.local, por ej)...